# Piping into rm command

Tags: unix

I`m going to delete all files from directory that contains "2" in their name. 
this command work well

```
 ls | grep [*2*]
```

but when i try to pipe the output from that command to command rm

```
 ls | grep [*2*] | rm
```

there is error "Try `rm --help' for more information."

please help

Comment: `rm` doesn't read file names from stdin; they're given as command line arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pipe output from another command to rm you must use xargs commant for rm 
Try this

```
ls | grep [*2*] | xargs rm
```

the output will send like arguments of rm command

Comment: By my count you've instantiated 4 processes whereas you can do this in 1 ?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the [wildcarding in the shell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) directly ?

e.g.

```
$ rm *2*
```

I don't think you need the `ls` *or* the `grep`. Your above problem stems from the fact that you're piping output into the stdin of `rm`, whereas you want to supply *command line arguments* to `rm`. `rm` doesn't read from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

you need to feed every line to rm command as an input. For this you need xargs along with pipe.

so modify the command like  `ls -1 | grep [*2*] | xargs rm -rf`

Answer (score 0):

just complementing on other answers, instead of running `ls` then `grep`, you could use `find`.

```
find . -name "*2*" | xargs rm
```